# I have solved a problem in CPLEX and now I want to implement it using an algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cplex

I have solved a problem in CPLEX and now I want to implement it using an algorithm in MATLAB. I have a decision variable that should take a value of 0 or 1.
In CPLEX , I defined that the value of the objective function is 0 or 1, depending on its value.

How do I enter the following code in MATLAB?

```
 dvar boolean value[N][M];

 minimize 

   sum(i in N, j in M)
   Response[i][j]* value[i][j];
```

Answer (score 0):

In [how to with OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/) you may see How to call OPL from [Matlab](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/callfrommatlab.M) ?

You may also check

https://github.com/mjbays/MATLAB-OPL-Interface

or 3rd option you may rewrite your OPL model into Matlab through [Matlab cplex API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/MATLAB/topics/cplex_matlab_overview.html)

you may also vote for the RFE (enhancement) have an OPL Matlab API : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=86414